# Use the week 01 Nix-shell for week 02?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix-shell

I'd like to know if we should use the week 01 nix-shell?

My expectation is that the week 01 nix-shell, was used to start the playground service and the front-end UI.

Although, it's clear that there's a need to have the *.nix files for `nix-shell` to work or startup, would be nice to hear from someone more experienced in nix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each week, you should change into the `plutus-pioneer-program` directory

```
cd plutus-pioneer-program
```

Pull the latest changes from upstream

```
git pull
```

View the `plutus-apps` git tag for the week in the `cabal.project` file. For week 2, look at `plutus-pioneer-program/code/week02/cabal.project`. [On line 63 you see the git tag](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week02/cabal.project#L63).

```
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
  tag: 6aff97d596ac9d59460aab5c65627b1c8c0a1528
```

Then change into `plutus-apps`

```
cd plutus-apps
```

Pull the latest changes from upstream

```
git pull
```

And checkout the appropriate tag

```
git checkout 6aff97d596ac9d59460aab5c65627b1c8c0a1528
```

Make sure you're in the `plutus-apps` directory and that you've checked out the correct tag. From there you can start as many Nix shells as necessary.

```
nix-shell
```

You may or may not want a Nix shell each for:

- starting the playground server
- starting the playground client
- building and serving Haddock docs
- starting a cabal REPL inside the appropriate week project
- building the cabal project

Comment: Thanks @Travis!